# Foreground service not receiving location updates in Android 7.0+ when screen is off

Tags: android, gps, location, android-7.0-nougat, wakelock

I am trying to create an Android application that continuously logs device location data in realtime while the device screen is off. My code works correctly with Android 6.0 and earlier but it seems that Android 7.0+ breaks my app.

I have implemented an Android foreground service that uses a wakelock and subscribes to the Google FusedLocation API. Once the screen is turned off the `onLocationChanged` callback is never triggered.

Has anyone seen a solution to this problem? I have tried disabling Battery Optimization through the Android Device Settings for my app as well as for the Google Services Framework and the Fused Location.

```
public class ForegroundLocationService extends Service implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = ForegroundLocationService.class.getSimpleName();

    // the notification id for the foreground notification
    public static final int GPS_NOTIFICATION = 1;

    // the interval in seconds that gps updates are requested
    private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 15;

    // is this service currently running in the foreground?
    private boolean isForeground = false;

    // the google api client
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    // the wakelock used to keep the app alive while the screen is off
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // create google api client
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        // get a wakelock from the power manager
        final PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (!isForeground) {

            Log.v(TAG, "Starting the " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());

            startForeground(ForegroundLocationService.GPS_NOTIFICATION,
                    notifyUserThatLocationServiceStarted());
            isForeground = true;

            // connect to google api client
            googleApiClient.connect();

            // acquire wakelock
            wakeLock.acquire();
        }

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.v(TAG, "Stopping the " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());

        stopForeground(true);
        isForeground = false;

        // disconnect from google api client
        googleApiClient.disconnect();

        // release wakelock if it is held
        if (null != wakeLock && wakeLock.isHeld()) {
            wakeLock.release();
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private LocationRequest getLocationRequest() {

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

        // we always want the highest accuracy
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        // we want to make sure that we get an updated location at the specified interval
        locationRequest.setInterval(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(0));

        // this sets the fastest interval that the app can receive updates from other apps accessing
        // the location service. for example, if Google Maps is running in the background
        // we can update our location from what it sees every five seconds
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(0));
        locationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS));

        return locationRequest;
    }

    private Notification notifyUserThatLocationServiceStarted() {

        // pop up a notification that the location service is running
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        final Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.foreground_location_service))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.service_is_running))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

        final Notification notification;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            notification = builder.getNotification();
        } else {
            notification = builder.build();
        }

        return notification;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        try {

            // request location updates from the fused location provider
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    googleApiClient, getLocationRequest(), this);

        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while requesting location updates", securityException);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Google API Client suspended.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to connect to Google API Client.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location.toString());
    }
}
```

I have included a complete working sample of the code that I am using to test here:
https://github.com/joshuajwitter/ForegroundLocationService

[FitBit seems to have the same issue, here is the discussion](https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Android-App/Android-Oreo-GPS-Issue/td-p/2177717)

Here are the resources that I have already looked at:

[Code Samples for Android O](https://developer.android.com/preview/o-samples.html)

[Keep app running in background on Android all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41599677/keep-app-running-in-background-on-android-all-the-time/41772487#41772487)

[Android, get the location when the screen is off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965789/android-get-the-location-when-the-screen-is-off)

[Background Location Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits.html)

[Inconsistent location updates in foreground service when in deep sleep (doze)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63937937)

[Foreground service not receiving location updates in Doze mode in Android O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811812/foreground-service-not-receiving-location-updates-in-doze-mode-in-android-o)

EDIT 2018.01.30: I have also tried running the ForegroundLocationService in its own process:

```
<service
    android:name="foregroundlocation.stackoverflowexample.com.foregroundlocation.ForegroundLocationService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:stopWithTask="false"
    android:process=":ForegroundLocationService"
    android:exported="false" >
</service>
```

as well as updating my code to use the `FusedLocationProviderClient`, still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried `.setOngoing(true)` when building your notification.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I just tried adding that however it didn't seem to make a difference:

        `final Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.foreground_location_service))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.service_is_running))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());`

Comment: Is `onLocationChanged` triggered when the screen is on though?

Comment: `onLocationChanged` is indeed triggered over and over when the screen is on. Once the screen turns off it is no longer triggered.

Comment: ..also it is triggered when the screen is on and the app is in the background (with the foreground service running).

Comment: Already answered here [Link to answer having complete code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55197117/4746976)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been experiencing this issue on emulated devices running 7.0 and 8.0 and consistently the location callback was not being triggered when the screen was off (cmd+P). I was finally able to get my hands on a real 7.0 device (Galaxy S7) and I was not able to replicate the issue. Sorry if I wasted anyone's time, apparently it is an emulator issue.

Comment: No it is not an emulator issue. I have experienced the same problem on real devices. I still did not find a solution though

Comment: @MMasmoudi me too, any luck on your side?

Answer (score 18):

I've spent the past week trying to get Location Services in Foreground. Finally got it working by including this in the manifest.

```
android:foregroundServiceType="location"
```

I hope this can help someone in the future!

Comment: I spent a whole day solving an issue. You are brilliant!!

Comment: Does it work, when the screen is turned off?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and I have found a working solution. In order to listen to location updates, you should NOT  call this method:

```
public Task<Void> requestLocationUpdates (LocationRequest request, 
LocationCallback callback, Looper looper)
```

You should use a pending intent instead of a callback, i.e. you should call the method:

```
public Task<Void> requestLocationUpdates (LocationRequest request, 
PendingIntent callbackIntent)
```

Checkout the link to read more: [https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest, android.app.PendingIntent)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Comment: can you provide some reference tutorial for this?

Answer (score 0):

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi is deprecated.

I just refactored my App as follows. Hope it helps:

This is what I am calling in the onCreate-Method of my Service:

```
public void start(Context ctx) {
        FusedLocationProviderClient client = LocationServices
                .getFusedLocationProviderClient(ctx);
        //Define quality of service:
        LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
        request.setInterval(1000); //Every second
        request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        if (locCallback != null) {
            client.removeLocationUpdates(locCallback);
        }
        locCallback = createNewLocationCallback();
        client.requestLocationUpdates(request, locCallback, null);
}
```

And this is the method for creating the Callback:

```
private LocationCallback createNewLocationCallback() {
    LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult result) {
            Location loc = result.getLastLocation();
            // Do something with the location (may be null!)
        }
    };
    return locationCallback;
}
```

Guess, I also found that somewhere as example, but did not keep the reference.

I do not have Oreo on my own. But some testers confirmed, that it works.

To keep the service in foreground, I am just calling "startForeground" afterwards in the onCreate method of my service.

Comment: Unfortunately this code does not seem to get updates while the screen is off. I substituted it for the code in my example and it did get the location at the scheduled interval until the screen was turned off, at which time no updates were received, then once the screen turned back on updates resumed.

Comment: This code also fails to get location updates while the screen is off on Nougat devices.

Comment: Did you try to return START_STICKY from onStartCommand of the service?

Comment: I took your suggestion and replaced START_REDELIVER_INTENT with START_STICKY, unfortunately it didn't make it work (thank you though for your response). It seems that the issue is that the location callback is never getting called when the screen is off. It's like the FusedLocationProvider itself stops when I turn off the screen, but I feel like that can't be because apps like Fitbit and Google Fit are able to track location with the screen off.

Comment: Any success on this. Going with same issue.

Answer (score 0):

one solution might be this :

check if location is not received in 2 minutes stop/start whole start location update again . although foreground service must have solve the problem